# Issues with modifier methods from two different classes

Tags: java, class, methods

I'm trying to call a method from another class, but we were never taught how to properly do that. I need my prodCompany in my movie class to get production information from my production class , but I'm not sure how to return that result with multiple varibales in my movie class.

```
\\My movie class:

   public void setProdCompany(String someName, String someCity, String someState) {
      prodCompany = someName + someCity + someState;
   }
   public String toString() {
      String result = "\nMovie Title:\t\t" + movieTitle + "\nMovie Length:\t\t" 
                + length + "\nMovie Year:\t\t" + year + "\nMovie Production:\t" +
                prodCompany + "\n\n";
        return result;
   }

\\From my production class:

 public class Production {
   private String companyName;
   private String locationCity; 
   private String locationState;

   public Production() {
      companyName = "?";
      locationCity = "?";
      locationState = "?";
   }

   public String getCompanyName() {
      return companyName;
   }
   public String getLocationCity() {
      return locationCity;
   }
   public String getLocationState() {
      return locationState;
   }
   public void setCompanyName(String someName) {
      companyName = someName;
   }
   public void setLocationCity(String someCity) {
      locationCity = someCity;
   }
   public void setLocationState(String someState) {
      locationState = someState;
   }
   public String toString() {
      String result = companyName + " at " + locationCity + " " + 
                locationState;
      return result;        
   }
}
```

Other than that everything works and my output is reading as follows:

```
Choice      Action
------      ------
A           Add Movie
D           Display Movie
Q           Quit
?           Display Help

What action would you like to perform? a
Please enter the Movie information:
Enter its title:  Field of Dreams
Enter its length: 107
Enter its year:   1989
Enter its production company name:     Gordon Company
Enter its production company's city:   Thomasville
Enter its production company's state:  NC
What action would you like to perform? D

Movie Title:        Field of Dreams
Movie Length:       107
Movie Year:         1989
Movie Production:   null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of making the `prodCompany` in your `Movie` class a string, you should make it of type `Production`.

It seems you want to initialize the production company with questionmarks. And then you can overwrite the name, city, and state of the production company. So your `Movie` class should look like this:

```
public class Movie {

    private Production prodCompany;

    public Movie() {
        prodCompany = new Production();
    }

    public void setProdCompany(String someName, String someCity, String someState) {
        prodCompany.setCompanyName(someName);
        prodCompany.setLocationCity(someCity);
        prodCompany.setLocationState(someState);
    }
...
```

Comment: thank you so much... Never learned it in class but we were supposed to know how to do it. appreciate ya

Answer (score 0):

you need to establish and understand the very basic logic of what is your actual method functionality and how to access another Class.
Let's see how this can be done:

```
public void getProdCompany() {  //Check here, there is no point passing arguments.
   Production prod = new Production();  // Calling your constructor and creating a Production instance.
   // From your Production instance:prod , you may access the getters of Production's private variables.
   prodCompany = prod.getCompanyName() + prod.getLocationCity() + prod.getLocationState();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before a call from another class, you need to instantiate it. After you can call its methods.

Like this:

```
private Production prodCompany = new Production();

public void setProdCompany(String someName, String someCity, String someState) {
    prodCompany = someName + someCity + someState;
```